# Using UserDefaults to store score for a clicker game (Swift 5)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uikit, nsuserdefaults

Have made a simple incremental game. I want it so that even if I go to a different VC and then return to the game, or reopen the game,  it will show the current score. My issue is that if I leave the game, then the score will return back to zero. I do not want that to happen. The score should not be resetting. I've heard I could use UserDefaults but I am not familiar to it at all. If you can explain using code, that would be best. Thanks.

```
import UIKit

class CookieClickerVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var goldLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfGold: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var getGoldButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formatItems()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(0, forKey: "goldCount")

}



@IBAction func getGoldClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    goldCount += 1
    numberOfGold.text = ("\(goldCount)")
}`
```

also, you may have already figured out, but goldCount is an unresolved identifier. How should I change the code after button is clicked?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step 1:** declare your `goldCount` variable and set the initial value to `0`

**Step 2:** on `viewDidLoad`, get the value stored in the `UserDefaults` and set it to `goldCount`

**Step 3:** Also update your label

**Step 4:** Update the value of `goldCount` in `userDefaults`

```
import UIKit

class CookieClickerVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var goldLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfGold: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var getGoldButton: UIButton!

    //Step1: declare your goldCount variable and set initial value to 0
    var goldCount = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        formatItems()
        //Step2: on viewDidLoad, get the value stored in the UserDefaults and set it to goldCount
        goldCount = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "goldCount")
        //Step3: then also update your label
        numberOfGold.text = ("\(goldCount)")


    }

    @IBAction func getGoldClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        goldCount += 1
        numberOfGold.text = ("\(goldCount)")
        //Step4: update the value of goldCount in userDefaults
        UserDefaults.standard.set(goldCount, forKey: "goldCount")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use these `funtions` to get and set score

```
class CookieClickerVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var goldLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfGold: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var getGoldButton: UIButton!


   lazy var goldCount : Int = 0 {
         didSet {
        numberOfGold.text = ("\(goldCount)")
       }
   }

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        formatItems()
        goldCount = getScore()

    }

    @IBAction func getGoldClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        goldCount += 1
        savescore(goldCount)
    }

    //  Save and Get methods ..

    func saveScore(_ score:Int) {
            let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
            defaults.set(score, forKey: "goldCount")
          //  defaults.synchronize() its [unnecessary][1] 
        }
```

> //  defaults.synchronize() its [unnecessary](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize)

```
    func getScore()-> Int {
          let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
          return  defaults.integer(forKey: "goldCount")
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import UIKit

class CookieClickerVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var goldLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfGold: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var getGoldButton: UIButton!

private var goldCount: Int = Int()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formatItems()

}



@IBAction func getGoldClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    goldCount += 1

    numberOfGold.text = ("\(goldCount)")

    UserDefaults.standard.set(goldCount, forKey: "goldCount")

    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

   //To get the count again you can use

     print(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "goldCount")
}
```

Whenever there is an increment you can save the value of `goldCount` like this in your `UserDefault` and I have also added how can you fetch the same value from `UserDefault`.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var numberOfGold: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var highScore: UILabel!

    //declare your count variable globally
    var goldCount : Int = 0
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //get the highscore and then set it to label
        let userHighScore = getUserScore()
        highScore.text = "\(userHighScore)"

    }

    @IBAction func goldButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
        goldCount += 1
        numberOfGold.text = "\(goldCount)"
    }

    //function to say game finished and store the score in userdefault
    //call this function when the gameHasFinished
    func gameFinished() {
        saveUserScore(goldCount)
    }

    func saveUserScore(_ score:Int){
        defaults.set(score, forKey: "goldCount")
    }
    func getUserScore()-> Int {
        return  defaults.integer(forKey: "goldCount")
    }
}
```

Comment: Apple says `synchronize()` [should not be used](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414005-synchronize), other than that it's an overall good solution!

Answer (score 2):

You can change your `viewDidLoad` function to check the `UserDefaults` for the "goldCount" key first, and if it has a value, use it. If not just set the score to 0.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formatItems()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    if let savedScore = defaults.value(forKey: "goldCount") as? Int {
        goldCount = savedScore
    } else {
        defaults.set(0, forKey: "goldCount")
    }
}
```

You can define "goldCount" as `var goldCount: Int = 0` below your `IBOutlet`s.

Also as a further optimization, you can extract the "goldCount" string to use as `let goldCountKey: String = "goldCount"` and use it like `defaults.set(0, forKey: goldCountKey)`. Avoiding hard-coded strings is a good practice in my opinion, but not that crucial in this case.

To save the new value in every click, add `UserDefaults.standard.set(goldCount, forKey: goldCountKey)` in `getGoldClicked`. Another idea here would be to add this in your `AppDelegate`'s `willTerminate` function to make sure you get your value saved when the application is terminated. Though that will require references to goldCount value there, so no rush.

Hope it helps!

Comment: `defaults.integer(forKey: "goldCount")` this is` non-optional` value. no need of if-let.

Comment: Right, my bad. I usually use value(forKey:) and cast it. Fixing the answer, thanks!